# How to fixed stripe payment integration error

Tags: php, stripe-payments, payment-gateway

I have integrate stripe payment on my website; work fine on local machine when check it on server; there is no response from server.
here is live url

http://eglobalsoft.com/stripe-checkout-demo/

Comment: check phpinfo(),Configure Command->'./configure' '--disable-dependency-tracking' '--prefix

Answer (score 0):

Your server is returning a `500` error. Check your server's error log, which you can likely access in a location such as `/var/log`.

Additionally as you are using PHP, you could try adding `error_reporting(E_ALL); 
ini_set("display_errors", 1);` to the top of your script temporarily and see if any errors are displayed in place!